# Problem with $n$ balls are placed into $n$ boxes using the Indicator Method

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, random-variables

> There are $n$ balls are placed into $n$ boxes, let $N_2$ be the number of boxes with exactly $2$ balls. Find the probability that $N_2 = n$ and the probability that $N_2 = n-1$. Use the method of indicators to compute $E(N_2)$.

I don't understand how to start this question. Does this mean if i have 5 boxes then I have 5 balls in which each box will contain a ball?

Or is it that only half of what $n$ is? So half the boxes will contain balls and the other half will not have balls?

Comment: A hint for you: what is a maximum value of random variable $N_2$? It can't be larger than $\frac {n} {2}$ - right?

Comment: i think this problem needs to assume uniformity or something